# Pyglet incorrectly interpreting all mouse clicks as left clicks

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to use pyglet on ubuntu 20.04, and the code is working except I have specified certain behavior on mouse drag with the left button held, (intending different behavior on when middle or right buttons are held) but `mouse.LEFT` is true even if it isn't a left mouse button, I have inserted a snippet below.

```
@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):

    if mouse.LEFT:
        chart.x_offset += float(dx)
        chart.y_offset += float(dy)
    elif mouse.RIGHT:
        chart.y_scale+=dy
```

It feels like it might be a bug/issue with interpreting mouse signals on Ubuntu, but I have no idea really, I am new to pyglet.

Thanks for reading

Comment: To debug this, check what is the value of `mouse.LEFT`. Since this variable is all uppercase, it is a constant. In other words, it will be the same value no matter what button you press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouse.LEFT` and `mouse.RIGHT` are constants. You have to evaluate if a specific bit is set in the `buttons` argument:

```py
@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):

    if buttons & mouse.LEFT:
        chart.x_offset += float(dx)
        chart.y_offset += float(dy)

    if buttons & mouse.RIGHT:
        chart.y_scale += dy
```

See further [pyglet - Working with the mouse](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/mouse.html).